# Optimize ActiveRecord queries. Is it possible to combine two queries into one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Optimize ActiveRecord queries. Is it possible to combine two queries into one?

I need get all records, and first record I use.

```
@appointments ||= @lead.appointments.order(created_at: :desc)

if appt = @appointments.first
  json.latest_appointment do
    json.partial! 'api/v1/lead_appointments/appointment', appointment: appt
  end
end

json.appointments do
  json.array! @appointments do |a|
    json.partial! 'api/v1/lead_appointments/appointment', appointment: a
  end
end
```

and get similar sql query

```
Appointment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "appointments".* FROM "appointments" WHERE "appointments"."lead_id" = $1 ORDER BY "appointments"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $2  [["lead_id", 760730], ["LIMIT", 1]]`
Appointment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "appointments".* FROM "appointments" WHERE "appointments"."lead_id" = $1 ORDER BY "appointments"."appointment_at" DESC  [["lead_id", 760730]]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change your `if` to

```
if appt = @appointments.to_a.first
```

This will cause your appointments to be loaded to an array with one query without limit, the `first` will work on an array and not cause an additional query to the DB and then when you render them all, they're already fetched from the DB.

Alternatively, your `if` can also be

```
if appt = @appointments[0]
```